# hey,I coudn't use the midbottom function in my pygame program. Every time I run my program I get to see my rect object on the bottom left

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-3.8, game-development, rect

```py
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and see its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # Start each ship at the bottom centre of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """"Update the ship's position based on movement flag."""
        # Update the ship's x value and not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        # Update rect object from self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at the current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

This is the code where ai_game is the instance from the main class.
everytime I run my code I see my rect object on the bottom left corner of the screen ,whereas the midbottom function should have placed my rect object (i.e the ship here) on the midbottom portion of the screen

Comment: Can you try and provide a small, but complete script that shows the wrong behavior when executed? e.g. not just the small excerpt from the class. I guess it has to do with you assigning `self.x` before `self.rect.midbottom`, but without more code it's hard to tell.

Comment: hey I've tried to edit my code, please check it out. Actually the problem is , when is run my code i get to see my rect object (i.e the ship here) on the bottom left side of the screen, whereas the midbottom function should have placed it on the midbottom portion of the screen , idk where am i going wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I couldn't be bothered to edit it. Your answer also covers approximately everything. Also, you seemed to be taking offense to my answer in general.

Comment: @MegaIng I apologize. On a first gaze, I thought your answer was identically. However, it is not. (I changed my answer because you deleted yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to set `self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom`. You also need to set `self.x` with `self.screen_rect.centerx`

```py
self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
self.x = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

Note that in the `update` method, `self.rect.x` is set by `self.x`. Therefore the `self.x` attribute needs to be initialized correctly

If you don't need the floating point accuracy you can completely remove the `self.x` attribute and use `slef.rect.centerx` instead.

Class `Ship`:

```py
class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and see its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each ship at the bottom centre of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        
        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """"Update the ship's position based on movement flag."""
        # Update the ship's x value and not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.centerx += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.centerx -= self.settings.ship_speed

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at the current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: tysm for helping me out , but can you please explain me why did we set self.x equal to self.screen_rect.centerx?

Comment: @user16622998 I've explained that in the answer. This is due to `self.rect.x = self.x` in the `update` method. You need to make sure that `self.x` is set correctly.

Comment: couldn't we assign self.x to self.rect_screen.midbottom?

Comment: @user16622998  `midbottom` is a tuple with a x and y component. You just want the "mid", but not the "bottom". "mid" is `self.screen_rect.centerx`.

Comment: Got it! tysm :)